# How to display the text in SDL2.ext?

Tags: python-3.x, sdl, pysdl2

How to work with the text in the SOM 2. There is a code. I do not understand what went wrong.

```
   bmpfont = sdl2.ext.BitmapFont(surface, (width, height)) 
   software_renderer = sdl2.ext.SoftwareSpriteRenderSystem(window) 
   factory = sdl2.ext.SpriteFactory(sdl2.ext.SOFTWARE) 
   sprite = factory.create_software_sprite((40, 40))

  surf = bmpfont.render("4").surface 
  sprite.surface = surf 
  software_renderer.render(sprite, 0, 0)
```

gives an error message:

```
ctypes.ArgumentError: argument 1: <class 'TypeError'>: expected LP_SDL_Surface instance instead of SoftwareSprite 
Exception ignored in:
```

Answer (score 0):

LP_ is a ctypes indicator for long pointers. You'll need to call the contents method on the LP object to get the object you want.